# Show ImagePicker in Popover - ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to show my UIImagePicker in ipad landscape mode..

I have followed this example: https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker

But I'm getting the following error:

```
<UIView: 0x7f8c9d158800; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f8c9d14f090>>'s window is not equal to <LoginRegisterViewController: 0x7f8c9ac51a70>'s view's window!
```

There's my code:

```
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

        UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = picker.popoverPresentationController;
        popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
        popPC.sourceView = btnImagemPerfil;
        popPC.sourceRect = btnImagemPerfil.bounds;
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(btnImagemPerfil.bounds));
        [self showViewController:picker sender:sender];
```

and the log from btnImagemPerfil.bounds

```
{{0, 0}, {141, 141}}
```

Comment: The error message says you have multiple windows. Explain.

Comment: There's my didFinishLauching code 

`self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    self.loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
     [FBLoginView class];
     [FBProfilePictureView class];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.loginRegisterView;
    [self irLoginRegister:nil];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.loginRegisterView;`

Comment: That code makes no sense at all (please, put code in your _question_, not in a comment). — Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: no..this project is old ;p using xib. This code is not part of my question..is part of your doubt

Comment: Okay but it still makes no sense. `[FBLoginView class]; [FBProfilePictureView class];` does nothing. `loginView` and `loginRegisterView` are two different things, so you're just throwing one of them away. Setting the root view controller twice makes no sense. Calling `irLoginRegister` might make no sense, for all I know.

Comment: try this [picker showInView:self.view]

Answer (score 2):

Updating my code to:

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self;

 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

        UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = picker.popoverPresentationController;
        popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
        popPC.sourceView = btnImagemPerfil;
        popPC.sourceRect = btnImagemPerfil.bounds;
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(btnImagemPerfil.bounds));
        [self showViewController:picker sender:sender];
```

it works for me